# How to get the battery level of bluetooth connected devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, watch, battery

iOS 9's battery widget in notification enter shows the battery level of the device itself, and other peripherals connected via bluetooth. (Apple pencil / Apple watch / BT speakers / BT headphones)

how to get those numbers in iOS?

Comment: Did you find out if that's possible somehow?

Comment: @iAlborz did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the possible method is to use CoreBluetooth and discover the connected devices. Connect to the Apple Watch and subscribe to it's service which shows the battery level of the device. This is a possible way for connected peripherials through bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, it does, at least a way to start researching.

Comment: @SwiftNinja that's encouraging! Would you mind sharing more details on how to go about that?